Python generate download link after upload file in Dropbox
Is there any way to generate download link to access file that already uploaded into dropbox.
Upload script:
dbx.files_upload(file.read(), "dropboxfolder/1.txt", mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode("overwrite"))

How about generate download link for giving to other user to download file.
Example: file is uploaded into path /dropboxfolder/1.txt at dropbox server.
Download link should be generated from dropbox system https://xxxxxdropbox.xcom./11/sssss
When user click link above will download file 1.txt at dropbox server
How to do that ?

The Dropbox API does offer ways to get links to files in a connected account.
Using the Dropbox Python SDK, to get a temporary link to a file, you can call the files_get_temporary_link method.
If you need a non-expiring link though, you can instead use the sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings method to create a shared link. Those links don't expire by default. Note that they do point to an HTML preview page by default but you can modify them for different behaviors as documented here.
